# OrderBy a SubQuery Criteria JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Im a new JPA criteria programmer and I need to orderBy this subQuery but orderBy just take order as params, any help please ?

```
 Subquery<Long> subQueryReplicationDetail = query.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<ReplicationDetail> replicationsDetail = subQueryReplicationDetail.from(ReplicationDetail.class);
    Predicate pred = null;
    pred = builder.equal(replicationsDetail.get(ReplicationDetailProperties.id); replications.get(ReplicationProperties.id));
    
                    subQueryReplicationDetail.select(builder.count(replicationsDetail.get(ReplicationDetailProperties.id))).where(pred);
    
    if (ReplicationDTO.COLUMN_NB_OBJECTS.equals(filter.getSortColumn())) {
                        query.orderBy(subQueryReplicationDetail);
                }
```

Comment: This seems more like an SQL question, not JPA: Order by can only be done on clauses included in the select. So how are you adding this subquery to your main query? (see JPA specification sections 4.9 and 6.5.14 for details)

Comment: I need to order by this query : ORDER  BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM replicationdetail replicatio5_ WHERE replicatio0_.idreplication = replicatio5_.replication_idreplication);

Comment: Yes, but how does this fit with your query? Unless you select this count value, you can’t order the rows by it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this instead:

```
query.orderBy(builder.asc(subQueryReplicationDetail));
```

The `orderBy` method takes `Order` objects that can be constructed with the `CriteriaBuilder`